# How add margin toolbar in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I add the title in toolbar of the book and a small icon on the right, with a large title, the text is superimposed on the picture. Indentation doesn't work. Is there a way to set boundaries when expanded

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bookImage"
                    app:title="Very Big size name of book. And Author"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/book"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp" 
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bookImage" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please add a screenshot or a design of what you're facing or expect? The question isn't clear.

Comment: i added a screenshot